# Can't launch sonar 2.8 (permission denied to execute wrapper )

Tags: linux, sonarqube, hp-ux

I'm new to Sonar, and i was trying to install Sonar 2.8 on my server (Linux 64 on HP-UX)

When i tried to launch it (sonar.sh start) i got the following message

```
[myHomeDirectory]/sonar/2.8/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper: Execute permission denied.
```

what drives me crazy is that i've putthe whole package on 777 permissions, so i really don't understand what's exactly happening.

Can anyone help with this please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You're new to Sonar and you're trying to install Sonar 2.8 which is 2 years old???... Come on!

Comment: it was not like i had a choice, sometimes you do what you want, sometimes you do what your customers want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came out with the conclusion that the binary file (wrapper) is simply not compiled to run under HP-UX

when launching a `file` command on wrapper under a Linux i get : `<ELF-64 executable object file>` which doesn't match the `<ELF-64 executable object file - IA64>` required by HP-UX running on a Itanium processor

Answer (score 14):

I hit a similar issue hence why I came to this post. I was attempting to install SonarQube's scanner in a Docker container but when I was running it, I was getting something along the lines of:

```
/root/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/bin//sonar-scanner: 103: exec: : Permission denied
```

I had given the whole /root/ folder all permissions so I was curious about the permission denied. In the end for me it wasn't anything to do with permissions. I simply needed to RTFM.

Sonar-scanner needs a JRE to run and my Docker container didn't have one installed. So if anyone else does the same thing as me, I hope this saves you a few minutes of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Not really convinced in the way you are launching it. To get Sonar running I recommend running it on tomcat, providing you just want to use the default database that comes with Sonar. The steps would be:

- Install Tomcat
- Navigate to your `/war` directory within your sonar instance and run the command: `$] ./build-war.sh`.

When this finishes you should see a sonar.war file in the same directory.

- Rename the war file ROOT.war instead of sonar.war: `$] mv sonar.war ROOT.war`

This ensures that sonar runs on tomcat's default port.

- Move the war file into the tomcat webapps directory: `$] mv ROOT.war /tomcathome/webapps`
- Navigate to the tomcat `/bin` folder and run the command `$] ./catalina.sh start`
- Type your server hostname in your browser with a port :8080 at the end and you should see sonar running.

These steps will have sonar running on the default database, though. If you want a MySQL database i'd look at sonar tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Actually i did install it that way on other machines, i met this issue only on my HP-UX machine

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have java installed on the machine. Java should be installed on the machine before running sonar-runner.

Use this to check java : java -version