# bin//sonar-scanner: 103: exec: : Permission denied

Tags: java, docker, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

While running a test build using Gitlab-CI + Sonarqube, it fails to execute the command `bin/sonar-scanner`. I get the error `103: exec:: Permission denied`.

It executes normally on the shell but not via the build automation using the CI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to a similar situation and response at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460784/2546381

It turned out to be that, the configured docker image, which Gitlab-runner is spinning up, has no Java installed in it and this script requires Java. It is also evident if we look into the sonar-scanner executable (which is a plain text shell script file).